# Biblatex formatting questions for bibliography

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibliographystyle

I have to format my bibliography according to the Oxford University Press style and am having trouble getting certain features with biblatex.

1. With item in a collection, how do I get a comma after the title, followed by lowercase "in", followed by the editors' names. The editors' names need to be abbreviated (e.g., "R. Frieden", but authors names must not be abbreviated. Like so:

> Chomsky, Noam (1991a). ‘Some Notes on Economy of Derivation and
> Representation’, in R. Freidin (ed.), Principles and Parameters in
> Comparative Grammar. Cambridge, MA: MIT Press, 417–54.

2. With articles, how do I get a colon after the volume number, as in this example:

> Hundius, Harald, and Ulrike Kölver (1983). ‘Syntax and Semantics of
> Numeral Classifiers in Thai’, Studies in Language 7: 165–214.

3. Again with articles, how do I get a comma after the title as opposed to a period, as in the above example?

Comment: Maybe this will help `https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/242267/using-definebibliographystrings-getting-undefined`

Comment: Before you go down the rabbit hole of customising `biblatex` styles, double check that your publisher can accept `biblatex` submissions. Many journals (and other publishers) cannot deal with the different workflow that `biblatex` requires, some journals/publishers have their own templates (including a bibliography style or at least instructions for the bibliography).

Comment: ... Anywho... if you want help with customisation of your style, it would be really, really great if you could post a small example document demonstrating your current bibliography style setup along with a few example entries so we have something to play around with. It is crucial that we know which style you are currently using because only then can we make sure that our suggestions work for you. (Such an example document is often called MWE https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864 or MWEB https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will help: [Having trouble forcing Overleaf to show "organization" field in the bibliography when using APA style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/595617/having-trouble-forcing-overleaf-to-show-organization-field-in-the-bibliography)

Also, have you configured biblatex correctly to use the referencing style that you need?

Comment: Mhhh, hard to say without knowing the exact requirements, but for me the style examples in the question do not really look like APA style (e.g. author names are not supposed to be abbreviated here, but APA style would shorten them, the name order would also be different for non-first authors).